# Segmentation fault when waiting for items to appear in a queue

Tags: c++, multithreading, queue

I have tried to speed up one of my projects by making it into a multi-threaded application. The project is a simple programming language. It has a parser, and interpreter. The parser parses files, and the interpreter interprets the tokens that the parser sends it. I moved the parser and interpreter to there own threads in order to eliminate downtime from when the parser gives the interpreter a token, and the parser ends up waiting on the interpreter to finish an operation instead of continueing to parse. In this way, the parser will be the producer and the interpreter will be the consumer. I was hoping that this would allow the parser to continue parsing while the interpreter interprets a token given by the parser. Though, at random times I will get a segmentation fault after the program finsihes. Sometimes the interpreter wont be able to see anything in the queue, or only get portions of whats inside of it. Other times it will run the same token twice. I'm not sure whats happening here, or why.

here is the relevant code used in the parser:

```
void threadedParse(std::string fileName, BambooVM *fileVM)
{
    // Queue that stores all of the tokens
    std::queue<Token> queue;

    std::thread thread(watch, std::ref(queue), fileVM);

    /* 
    ...
    */

    while (std::getline(file, line)) {
        // Push tokens to queue, read file, etc
    }

    /* 
    ...
    */
  
    // Wait for the queue to empty after parsing all tokens
    while (!queue.empty())
        continue;
    
    thread.detach();

}
```

The function "watch", watches the provided queue and waits for elements, when it finds one it should interpret that element and pop it off the queue.

```
void watch(std::queue<Token> &queue, BambooVM *vm)
{
    Utils::debug("Starting interpreter...");
    while (1)
    {
        if (!queue.empty())
        {
            interpret(queue.front(), vm);
            queue.pop();
        }
    }
}
```

What I have done to try and solve the issue:

- [Used a blocking & non blocking SPSC queue](https://github.com/cameron314/readerwriterqueue)
- Using state variables (`int *state`, 1 meaning item ready to consume, 0 meaning empty ) instead of `queue.empty()` to try and control when we consume tokens.

Something that should be noted: The parser may run slower than the interpreter at times, aswell as the interpreter being slower than the parser. I dont wish to ever have the interpreter waiting on the parser unless there are no elements to be interpreted. The parser should also never have to wait on anything, and should always be active.

I am new to threads and multi-threaded applications, I apologize if my question is not clear. I tried to make it as plain as possible.

Comment: You have a race condition (Undefined Behavior), since two threads are accessing your `std::queue<Token>` with modification and without synchronization.

Comment: Almost always, `thread.detach();` is a Bad Thing.  It means you'll need to coördinate the graceful thread termination using other means, which is typically a Hard Problem.

Comment: `thread.detach()` allows the thread to continue to execute after the end of your function but `queue` is destroyed at the end of your function, `detach` is rarely the right approach. You either need to put `queue` somewhere it lives longer or not detach the thread and `join` instead

Comment: It doesn't look like you're doing anything to synchronize the access to `queue` which means it's entirely possible for the background thread to have `queue.empty()` return `false`, but `queue.front()` being undefined behaviour. The simplest solution would be to add a mutex for synchronization and do something like `std::string token; { std::lock_guard g(theMutex); if (q.empty()) { continue;  } token = std::move(q.front()); q.pop(); } interpret(token, vm);`

Comment: Probably you should be using a condition variable instead of a busy wait loop though or at least an `std::atomic<bool>` to avoid unnecessary locking of the mutex.

Answer (score 2):

You really need to use some mutex locking and probably a condition variable.

```
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

std::mutex myMutex;
std::condition_variable condVar;

...

void addToQueue() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(myMutex);
    ... add to the queue
    condVar.notify_all();
}

void doWork() {
    while(true) {
         std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(myMutex);
         if (queue is empty) {
             condVar.wait();
             continue;
         }
         ... queue has something in it.
    }
}
```

This isn't tested, although I'm cutting and pasting from some of my own code.

Comment: Note that this is such a design pattern that I write some pretty fully-featured templated classes for holding random objects in my queue. It's worth learning and writing it well.

Comment: Using `continue` to check for spurious wakes will cause the lock to unlock then re-lock. You can use `while(queue.empty())` instead, or use the overload of `wait` that takes a predicate.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux though note that the predicate version locks and unlocks the mutex each time it runs

Comment: While this is not the solution I ended up implementing, thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: @AlanBirtles As a minimum, each `wait` has to necessarily unlock then relock the mutex. The solution provided in this answer causes an additional unlock/relock on top of that, if there is a spurious wake. Using the other overload, a `while` loop or moving the lock out of the loop eliminates it.